# Isset is not working with mysqli_query

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, mysqli, isset

So when using an if !isset statement in my program it isn't recognizing that the variable has been set. I have set it up so that if a variable $q isn't set then to get a query from my mysqli database. This query will get back the latest entry of data from my database. This data equals a variable called $row. $row variable is called later on to retrieve records that are then displayed on the webpage. The problem is that the if statement runs again (when refreshing/reloading the page) even though $q has been set from last time the .php file ran. Here is the code:

```
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "music_reviews_database";
$db_host = "localhost";

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!isset($q)) {
    $q = mysqli_query($conn, 
            "SELECT album.Album, 
            artist.ArtistsName, 
            datereviewed.DateReviewed, 
            features.Features, 
            genre.Genre, 
            rating.Rating, 
            songname.SongName,
            link.link,
            songname.ID,
            comments.Comments
            FROM songname 
            INNER JOIN album ON album.ID = songname.ID 
            INNER JOIN artist ON artist.ID = songname.ID
            INNER JOIN datereviewed ON datereviewed.ID = songname.ID
            INNER JOIN features ON features.ID = songname.ID
            INNER JOIN genre ON genre.ID = songname.ID
            INNER JOIN rating ON rating.ID = songname.ID
            INNER JOIN link ON link.ID = songname.ID
            INNER JOIN comments ON comments.ID = songname.ID
            ORDER BY DateReviewed DESC LIMIT 1");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($q);
}
```

So the code should be like this instead?

```
$q = mysqli_query($conn, 
        "SELECT album.Album, 
        artist.ArtistsName, 
        datereviewed.DateReviewed, 
        features.Features, 
        genre.Genre, 
        rating.Rating, 
        songname.SongName,
        link.link,
        songname.ID,
        comments.Comments
        FROM songname 
        INNER JOIN album ON album.ID = songname.ID 
        INNER JOIN artist ON artist.ID = songname.ID
        INNER JOIN datereviewed ON datereviewed.ID = songname.ID
        INNER JOIN features ON features.ID = songname.ID
        INNER JOIN genre ON genre.ID = songname.ID
        INNER JOIN rating ON rating.ID = songname.ID
        INNER JOIN link ON link.ID = songname.ID
        INNER JOIN comments ON comments.ID = songname.ID
        ORDER BY DateReviewed DESC LIMIT 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($q);
file_put_contents(data.php, return var_export($row,true));
if (file_exists(data.php)) {
    $row = include(data.php);
}
```

Comment: Where are you initialising $q?

Comment: You dont mention $q variable thats the reason its not recognizing

Comment: Oh ok would there be a way to initialize the query just once then as that is why i was trying to use isset in the first place. Because if new data is inserted into the database then the query will overwrite the data I want with the latest data if that makes sense

Comment: Set variable query for the `$q = 'something';` i really dont you looking for POST Submit isset?

Comment: If the $q = 'something' though then won't the if statement never run since $q has been set to 'something'

Comment: Change to isset($conn) from isset($q). And if you want to retain state then save it under if condition with $_SESSION['q']. Then you can easily do isset($_SESSION['q']). It wont run after refreshing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just remove

```
if (!isset($q)) {
```

and the closing bracket. They are unnecessary.

If you want to avoid running the query each time to get results, try caching the results.

E.g.

after you get the results from query, send the contents to a file somewhere in the filesystem ($path)

```
file_put_contents($path, '<?php return '.var_export($mysql_row,true).';?>');
```

Then you can read it back out:

```
if (file_exists($path)) $mysql_row = include($path);
```

So something like:

```
if (file_exists(data.php)) {
    $row = include(data.php);
}else{
      $q = mysqli_query($conn, 
        "SELECT album.Album, 
        artist.ArtistsName, 
        datereviewed.DateReviewed, 
        features.Features, 
        genre.Genre, 
        rating.Rating, 
        songname.SongName,
        link.link,
        songname.ID,
        comments.Comments
        FROM songname 
        INNER JOIN album ON album.ID = songname.ID 
        INNER JOIN artist ON artist.ID = songname.ID
        INNER JOIN datereviewed ON datereviewed.ID = songname.ID
        INNER JOIN features ON features.ID = songname.ID
        INNER JOIN genre ON genre.ID = songname.ID
        INNER JOIN rating ON rating.ID = songname.ID
        INNER JOIN link ON link.ID = songname.ID
        INNER JOIN comments ON comments.ID = songname.ID
        ORDER BY DateReviewed DESC LIMIT 1");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($q);    
        file_put_contents(data.php, '<?php return '.var_export($row,true).';?>');
    }
```

Comment: Ok. The reason I wanted the isset was so that the mysqli_query would just run once (i.e. if the page was refreshed/reloaded it wouldn't run the query again). Is there any way to do this? Can I just POST submit isset (if so how?)

Comment: Awesome where does the $mysql_row come from though

Comment: `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($q);` same thing, just a different variable name, name it as you wish

Comment: OK thank you and $path is just the url of the file right and these two lines of code would just go after the query or would the query be inside the if(file_exists) statement

Comment: yes path will be the place on the filesytem including the filename. So you'd run your query in your question only if the file didn't exist at the path. If it does exist, you just include it.

Comment: you just put return, instead of the whole php statement

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it still says syntax error unexpected return.

Comment: haha, I copied your code, so that's why it would have shown an error, try the updated code

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! I have literally been trying to figure out how to solve this problem the whole day. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that the if statement runs again (when refreshing/reloading the page)  even though `$q` has been set from last time the .php file ran.

Each PHP script handles a single HTTP request. When the script completes, all its context (HTTP request, HTTP response, variables etc) is destroyed. A new request is handled by a new instance of the script that doesn't know anything about its previous invocation.

If you need to pass information from one execution of the PHP script to the next you can use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). However, explaining how the sessions work is a subject too broad for a [so] answer.